# Under what circumstances will the constructor of apache.commons.csv.CSVPrinter throw an IOException?

Tags: java, csv, apache-commons, apache-commons-csv

According to [the documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVPrinter.html#CSVPrinter-java.lang.Appendable-org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat-) of org.apache.commons.csv.CSVPrinter, an IOException will be thrown "if the optional header [provided in the second argument] cannot be printed". But what would *cause* the optional header to be unable to print? Are some strings somehow invalid in the header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the source of `org.apache.commons.csv.CSVPrinter`](https://github.com/apache/commons-csv/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVPrinter.java), the constructor you link to writes any header comments, and the CSV header (if used), to the output stream given in the parameter `out`.  As this involves writing to the output stream, there is the possibility that an `IOException` may be thrown.

Comment: Oooh. When I was reading the documentation, I thought it was implying that some headers were invalid, but it was simply saying that some Appendables throw IOExceptions. Got it. Thanks.